# Lof JSliderNews URL problem

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to install Lof JSliderNews on my website and everything is working well, the pictures and the titles are swicthing fine but the URLs don't. It seems like they always point to the latest post.

I've been looking around now for quite a while but couldn't find any solution. Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Thanks for your Help.

Lita

Comment: Please specify your JSlider plug-in URL.

Comment: here's the link http://landofcoder.com/demo/jquery/lofslidernews/index5.html

Answer (score 3):

Dude.

i've been cracking my head off tru the table trying to figure out the issue, and it's a simple CSS mistake.

check on the style6.css (that came inside on the .zip file) and check that :

> .lof-main-item-desc{
>     z-index:100px; <<--- this line it's wrong.
>     position:absolute;
>     bottom:0px;
>     left:0px;
>     width:100%;
>     background:url(images/bg_trans.png);
>     height:45px;
>     padding:10px;
>     
>   }

---

replace it for this:

> .lof-main-item-desc{
>     z-index:100;
>     position:absolute;
>     bottom:0px;
>     left:0px;
>     width:100%;
>     background:url(images/bg_trans.png);
>     height:45px;
>     padding:10px;
>     
>   }
>   
>   (remove the px on the z-index) after the 100 and that's is.

Cheers

ck.

Answer (score 2):

Lita,

Because attribute 'opacity' doesn't make link hidden, and 'z-index' of the last link is above its siblings, so we must modify script to set z-index.

The original scripts(in lofslidernews/js/script.js):

```
fxStart:function( index, obj, currentObj ){
            if( this.settings.direction == 'opacity' ) { 
                $(this.slides).stop().animate({opacity:0}, {duration: this.settings.duration, easing:this.settings.easing} );
                $(this.slides).eq(index).stop().animate( {opacity:1}, {duration: this.settings.duration, easing:this.settings.easing} );
            }else {
                this.wrapper.stop().animate( obj, {duration: this.settings.duration, easing:this.settings.easing} );
            }
        return this;
    }
```

Replace it with the following script:

```
fxStart:function( index, obj, currentObj ){
            if( this.settings.direction == 'opacity' ) { 
                $(this.slides).css('z-index',-1).stop().animate({opacity:0}, {duration: this.settings.duration, easing:this.settings.easing} );
                $(this.slides).eq(index).css('z-index',10).stop().animate( {opacity:1}, {duration: this.settings.duration, easing:this.settings.easing} );
            }else {
                this.wrapper.stop().animate( obj, {duration: this.settings.duration, easing:this.settings.easing} );
            }
        return this;
    }
```

I have solved this problem by this way, Wish it is helpful to you!